# Correction to ng2-opd-popup

Tags: css, angular

## When I add a form to the window is arranged like this:

[image]

## but I need:

[image]

In file: popup.component.html:

```
<div id="ng2-opd-popup-main"
     *ngIf="visible" [ngClass]="mainClass" [ngStyle]="mainStyle">
    <div class="row">
        <div style="display: inline-block;width:100%">
           <div id="ng2-opd-popup-well"  [ngStyle]="wellStyle"
                class="ng2-opd-popup-well ng2-opd-popup-well-sm">
             {{popupService.options.header}}
           </div>
        </div>
    <div style="margin:20px;">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
        <div *ngIf="popupService.options.showButtons"
              style="margin-bottom:20px;margin-top:20px;float: right">
            <button id="cancelBtn" [ngClass]="cancelBtnStyle"
                    type="reset" (click)="confirmNo()">
              {{popupService.options.cancleBtnContent}}
            </button>
            <button id="confirmBtn" [ngClass]="confirmBtnStyle" 
                    (click)="confirmYes()">
              {{popupService.options.confirmBtnContent}}
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

When I change line `<div style="margin:20px;">`on **`<div style="margin:20px; width:100%">`** Nothing happens
The application does not respond to my code changes. What is the problem?

Comment: Have you tried using `!important`?

Comment: The problem must be somewhere in the compilation probably. Every change made to this file does not update

Comment: You could work around that by adding your own custom CSS that traverses the DOM looking for the div you need. You could use `#ng2-opd-popup-main` as a good starting place. As long as you use `!important` in your custom styling it should override the existing style.

Comment: `#ng2-opd-popup-main div:nth-child(2) {
  width: 100% !important;
}` It works. But is that correct?

Comment: What do you mean by correct?

Comment: I wonder why I can not change in a component Angular. It would be more natural

Comment: I wouldn't suggest changing 3rd party code.